# Cómo ingresar datos en el servidor y que me aparezcan en xampp, phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

estoy intentando llenar un formulario en el servidor(los documento están guardados en una carpeta en xampp/htdocs) pero reviso en la tabla de mi BD en Phpmyadmin y la información que ingreso no se guarda.!
Ya intenté hacerlo de 2 formas pero ninguna me funciona acá está la forma, 
más sencilla teniendo en cuenta que el formulario hecho como html(guardado .php) corre

Documento datos.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $server="localhost";
        $user="root";
        $password="";
        $bd="ejemplo";
        $conectarsecon=@mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $bd);
        if(!$conectarsecon){    
            echo "No se conectó con la Bd";
        }else {
            $bdd=@mysqli_select_db('ejemplo');
            if($bdd){
                echo "Se seleccionó la BD: ejemplo";
            }else{
                echo "No se ha podido seleccionar ninguna BD";
            }
            if (!$bdd) {
                echo "Esta bd no existe verifica tu Bd";
            }
        }
        $nombr=$_POST['nombre'];
        $clave=$_POST['clave'];
        //la linea sgt es la sentencia
        $sql="INSERT INTO *from mibd values ('$nombr', '$clave')";

        $ejecutarlasentenciasql=@mysqli_query($sql);

        if(!$ejecutarlasentenciasql){
            echo "La tabla no se encuentra en tu Bd";
        }else{
            echo "Se guardaron los datos <a href='formulario.php'>deseas volver</a>";
        }
        ?>
    </body>
    </html>

El formulario esta hecho como html pero guardado como .php 'formulario.php'
```

Agradezco la colaboración.-

Answer (score 1):

*****Ojo muy importante leer los comentarios *****

Revisando tu formulario checa bien si estas ejecutando la consulta correctamente 
ya que revisando tu formulario

esta consulta esta mal

$sql="INSERT INTO *from mibd values ('$nombr', '$clave')";

Ya que quizas sea porque entre el * y from no tienen espacio

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $server="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $password="";
    $bd="ejemplo";
    $conectarsecon=@mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $bd);
    if(!$conectarsecon){    
        echo "No se conectó con la Bd";
    }else {
        $bdd=@mysqli_select_db('ejemplo');
        if($bdd){
            echo "Se seleccionó la BD: ejemplo";
        }else{
            echo "No se ha podido seleccionar ninguna BD";
        }
        if (!$bdd) {
            echo "Esta bd no existe verifica tu Bd";
        }
    }
    $nombr=$_POST['nombre'];
    $clave=$_POST['clave'];
    //la linea sgt es la sentencia
    $sql="INSERT INTO *from mibd values ('$nombr', '$clave')";//Revisa bien la consulta si la tiene correcta

    $ejecutarlasentenciasql=@mysqli_query($sql);

    if(!$ejecutarlasentenciasql){
        echo "La tabla no se encuentra en tu Bd";
    }else{
        echo "Se guardaron los datos <a href='formulario.php'>deseas volver</a>";
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

El formulario esta hecho como html pero guardado como .php 'formulario.php'

Comment: Ya lo guardé con el espacio y no!

Comment: intenta utilizando este metodo de conección

$usu = "root";
$pwd = "";
$dbname ="ejemplo";
$local = "localhost";

$db =  mysqli_connect($local,$usu,$pwd,$dbname);

if($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}


y para las consultas intenta hacerlo asi 

$query = $db->query("escribe la consulta aqui ")

Comment: Gracias Ramiro RM, ya la pude hacer como marco su respuesta como acertada?

Comment: Al lado de la respuesta aparece una palomita la seleccionas,

Comment: Solo aparece la bandera